Comp Vocal Take — Automatic Selection [AI plugin?] (Logic Pro X)
my first time posting.
I record a lot of sessions, lot of vocal takes. and the compositing process can be tedious. The end product is always better for it though of course.
I would love to know if there are any features, software or plugins that maybe even incorporate AI to automatically select and present a few diff comps.
Then, thereafter a human could look through, say, 1-5 vocal comps and use bits of them to form a final draft.
Would be insane to see/know of anything like this. The power would be incredible, selecting for different modes like - most enunciated, or softest takes vs loudest or deepest pitch etc.
